# Java: how to use try/catch block with return

Tags: java, list, exception

The following code throws an exception if the list is empty and I want to `getLast()`. Also, I want to modify it with `throw/catch`-blocks, so that the message of the exception is going to appear on the console.

```
double foo(double[] numbers, double n) {
    LinkedList<Double> list = new LinkedList<Double>();
    for (double x : numbers) {
        if (x > 0 && x <= n && x % 2 != 0) {
            list.add(x);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    return list.getLast();
}
```

My idea was:

```
double foo(double[] numbers, double n) {
    LinkedList<Double> list = new LinkedList<Double>();
    for (double x : numbers) {
        if (x > 0 && x <= n && x % 2 != 0) {
            list.add(x);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    try{
        return list.getLast();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("caught: " + e);
    }
    return list.getLast();
}
```

Is this right? Did the exception get caught? What about the code after the `throw/catch`-block? Is it going to execute? If yes, is the exception going to be thrown again by `return list.getLast();`?

Comment: The problem is with `return list.getLast();` **after** the try-catch block. The idea with the `catch` block is to do something after problematic statements fail. You may need to change that last line to something like `return new ArrayList<Double>()` or default implementation that makes sense in case of error.

Comment: Yes, the exception would be caught for the first `list.getLast();` and it will print the debug line, but as you suspect, the second `list.getLast();` will throw the same exception which will bubble-up out of `foo`. As Ernest says, you probably want to either return a default value such as `0` or actually catch the exception in the caller.

Comment: Why would a caller of this code provide a null/empty `numbers`?  Is it really this method's responsibility to handle that situation?  If yes, *how* is it supposed to handle it when the input is meaningless?  Just return 0? Or possibly check for null/empty and throw an IllegalStateException or maybe a checked exception to force the caller to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `list.getLast()` throws an exception, it will be caught and the message will be printed. Then you will do the *exact same thing* and throw the exact same exception.

If you are relying on that exception being thrown when the list is empty, consider *rethrowing* the exception:

```
try {
  return list.getLast();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Caught: " + e);
  throw e; // re-throw
}
// no "return" outside since we'll have thrown our previously caught error.
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the error `error: unreachable statement
    return list.getLast();`

Comment: If you rethrow the error, you can't have a return outside of the try-catch, like the comment says.

Answer (score 0):

- Is this right? **If you want the exception to be thrown after print, it might be right functionality-wise, but calling getLast() twice is not the "right" way to do it.**
- Did the exception got caught? **Yes, it did.**
- What about the code after the throw/catch-block? Is going to execute? **Yes, it is going to execute. Since the exception was caught and not re-thrown, the execution continues as usual.**
- If yes, by return list.getLast(); is the exception going to be thrown again? **Yes, the exception will be thrown again.**

---

I think what you are looking for is:

```
try {
    return list.getLast();
} catch (Exception e){
  System.out.println("caught: " + e); // consider e.printStackTrace()
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get last", e);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the error `error: unreachable statement
    return list.getLast();`

Comment: Did you remove the return list.getLast() that you added after the catch block?

Answer (score 0):

Why use try / catch at all.  If all you want to do is determine if the list is empty what about checking `list.size() != 0`?   Then return `list.getLast()` if true or `Double.Nan` and a message to the console if false.

Comment: It could be that the calling/downstream code relies on the exception being thrown.

Comment: I considered that but the examples do not seem to indicate that the error is being passed on.